# UIScrollView frame property

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, frame

I have used Interface Builder to draw a simple UI with a scrollview,
in viewDidLoad I am reading off the x, y, width and height of scrollview's frame CGRect property like this:

```
    NSLog(@"x=%f,y=%f,w=%f,h=%f",self.detailScrollView.frame.origin.x,self.detailScrollView.frame.origin.y,self.detailScrollView.frame.size.width,self.detailScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

(offcourse previously properly @syntheized everything and I have correct IBOutlets etc..)

but when I look at the readoffs and compare them to the interface builder values I am little bit confused about the y coordinate, everything else (x,width,height) is OK.

This is the output from NSLog:

```
 2012-08-06 15:52:40.481 xxxxx[1471:207] x=20.000000,y=147.000000,w=280.000000,h=293.000000
```

But the actual values from the interface builder for the scrollview are:
X=20 Y=59 Width=280 Height=293 (sorry I cannot post screencapture).

Any hints why the y value is offset by 88 ? (147 in NSLog minus 59 in interface builder)
Thanks

Comment: You are not supposed to see at `viewDidLoad` the frame which will be displayed, that might be either the orientation change, autoresizing or something else that is not processed before `viewDidLoad` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and fixed it by changing the autosizing. I set both the inner and outer box and it worked for me.